# How to check Update query effected columns in a trigger SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am creating a trigger on a table for update. The table on which the trigger is to be defined contains more than 30 columns. Now I want to know, which columns have been effected by the update query, so that I can take necessary action when certain columns values change. Please just name any method that can achieve such functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think you should use `COLUMNS_UPDATED()` provided by `SQL Server`
>   for this purposes.

It tells you exactly which columns changed. Examples can be found  **[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

There is `COLUMNS_UPDATED()` for you but it is a lit bit complicated. You might want to stick to:

```
IF UPDATE(SomeColumn) OR UPDATE(SomeOtherColumn)
```